# CMD delete files

Tags: cmd, delete-file

Perhaps someone can be of help; I have several files with the following naming convention:

```
fooR1.txt, fooR2.txt, fooR3.txt, . . . , fooR1000.txt
```

I wish to delete all the files greater than R500. I have several folders and I know how to pass through each folder, but I am not sure how to capture and delete the files with replication 501 and greater. How can I do such?

Comment: This type of questions should be asked at SU.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply:

```
ren foo500.txt foo499bis.txt
del fooR5??.txt fooR6??.txt fooR7??.txt fooR8??.txt fooR9??.txt fooR10??.txt 
ren foo499bis.txt foo500.txt
```

Not elegant, but efficient.

Comment: Perfect! I completely forgot I can use ? in CMD.

Comment: @StefanieMcDonald `fooR5??.txt` will match also `fooR5.txt`, `fooR50.txt` etc. Run a dir with it first to make sure you do not delete more than you wished for!

Comment: Indeed...it deleted more than I wanted. I will try the other options. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will delete all files `fooR###.txt` where ### is greater than 500.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%f in (fooR*.txt) do (
  set num=%%~f
  set num=!num:~4,-4!
  if !num! gtr 500 del /q "%%~f"
)

endlocal
```

Comment: You need `del /q "fooR!num!".txt`, don't you? `!num!` at the point of the delete only contains the number itself.

Comment: And, FIW, your could would also match a file named `fooRa.txt` (i.e. where everything after `fooR` is not numeric) - although whether that would be an issue is for the OP to decide.

Comment: @Christian.K The OP wasn't saying anything about other files, so I wasn't accounting for that. And of course that should have been `del /q "%%~f"`. Thanks for the heads up, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Because your range is open, I've reversed your criteria: delete anything that is not in the range 1-499. Please be aware that this is **not exactly equivalent** to yours, for example it will also delete a file named `fooR001.txt` or `fooR_something_else.txt`
It's also pretty slow.

```
@echo off
for %%F in (fooR*.txt) do (
  echo %%F | findstr  /v /r "fooR[1-9]\.txt fooR[1-9][0-9]\.txt  fooR[1-4][0-9][0-9]\.txt" >nul  && echo del %%F
)
```

First line (`for`) enumerates files starting with `fooR`, then for each file `findstr` checks if it does **not** match pattern (`/v` option) and finally a command is executed if a check (ie does not match) is positive (`&&` means *execute only if previous command was successfull*).
Code above will just echo commands, not execute them, so you may safely run it to verify it actually behaves as it should. To actually run delete, just remove `echo` in front of it.

note: you could actually run this directly from command line in a form of:

```
@for %F in (fooR*.txt) do @echo %%F | findstr  /v /r "fooR[1-9]\.txt fooR[1-9][0-9]\.txt  fooR[1-4][0-9][0-9]\.txt" >nul  && echo del %F
```

Answer (score -1):

You would need to make a Batch script for this. Then in the Batch file you could write.

```
DEL "fooR500.txt"
```

To delete all files with a .txt ending you would just write:

```
DEL "*.txt"
```

That's all I know, but if you want to get it so it does files 500 and higher you would have 
to create a variable in Batch that holds the value 500 using:

```
set Value = 500
```

and then have it delete file "fooR" + Index + ".txt" so to do that you would have to do:

```
set "FilePre = fooR"
set "FileW  = %FilePre% %Value%"
set "Ex = .txt"
set "FileX = %FileW% %Ex%"
del FileX
```

Then you will have to make Value go up by one and repeat the process 500 times until it reaches 1000.

Comment: That is all very awkward: (1) it is not an answer to the OPs question. (2) setting variables the way you do creates names with a trailing blank. For example `FilePre` will actually by only usable as `%FilePre %` (note the space).

Comment: (1) it is the answer to delete files 500-1000 and (2) I am not an amazing Batch programmer, I just used what I remembered doing. Thanks for the input though, even though I don't really care what you have to say.

Comment: Your "answer" is to delete either the file `fooR500.txt` itself, or all files with the extensions `*.txt` - or a file name `FileX` (the very last line of code). Neither of which was what the OP asked for. It is not expected that you are an amazing batch programmer to answer here, but you should at least check that the answer you post actually works, at least kind of. If you don't put that much effort in your answer, you just have to live with people telling you so.

Comment: I got it to work myself.. and if you read the whole post it explains how to delete 500 to 1000

Comment: You can only mean the lines starting with `set Value = 500` and following? "Logically", one could deduce that they should do what you advertise, but syntactically they are broken all over. For example, they will only delete a single file named `FileX`. At the very least you would have needed to do a `del "%FileX %"`, but even that wouldn't work, because "%FileX %" doesn't expand to what you (apparently) think it would (Hint: don't use spaces before/after the `=` and between "concatenating" your variables to filenames. If you really got it to work, then you should update your answer.

Comment: Really it's pointless talking to you because I don't even care for your input in the first place.